# count number of style tags in div container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to count the total number of img elements and then the number of style tags present in a parent div tag using jquery.  The current HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="origin" class="ui-test">
    <div class="polaroid ui-test">
        <img src="http://example.com/84655/l/72105d6f46205a948f00f6e59c299930.jpg" >
    </div>
    <div class="polaroid ui-test">
        <img src="http://example.com/77676/l/819e2093be4c61d2e21b1175f9d0f0f9.jpg" >
    </div>
    <div class="polaroid ui-test" style="left: 288.328125px; top: -8px; display: none;">
        <img src="http://example.com/47901/l/79f936ef9847793254bad21e16b2448f.jpg" >
    </div>
    <div class="polaroid ui-test" style="left: 94.328125px; top: 6px; display: none;">
        <img src="http://example.com/49761/l/6d10064d6b189c6934fd264ac295f5f8.jpg" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Based on the above example I'm trying to get a count of total img elements under the parent origin container and then how many are showing `display: none;`

I would expect to see: 4 img tags total and 2 hidden img tags

I think I can get the toital number of images with the following:

```
var totalImages = $("#origin img").length;
```

How do I get the total number of images showing display:none?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var totalImages = $("#origin img").length;
var totalImagesWithStyle = $("#origin div[style] img").length;
//or
var totalImagesWithStyle = $("#origin div:hidden img").length;
//or
var totalImagesWithStyle = $("#origin .polaroid:hidden img").length;
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5HVhR/)

Answer (score 0):

The [:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector selects all elements that are hidden.

`$( "#origin div:hidden" ).length;`

Comment: See my comment on blurd's answer. `$('#origin .polairoid:hidden img').length` would do the trick though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `:hidden` [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/).

```
 $('#origin img:hidden');
```

Comment: The images are not hidden; the parents are (class .polaroid).

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/35uvZ/. It consists of your HTML part; I left the left and top declarations. Other than that just some jQuery:

```
var $imgWrp = $('#origin .polaroid');
var $images = $imgWrp.find('img');
var $hiddenImages = $imgWrp.filter(':hidden').find('img');

console.log($images.length);
console.log($hiddenImages.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency, I would break it up into two steps:

```
var allImages = $("#origin").find("img");
var hiddenImages = allImages.filter(":hidden");
```

Then you could retrieve the lengths of either or both sets (as needed) and proceed from there.